# RAD - Web Sphere 7.0 Server is not getting started

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I am working in RAD 7.5.0 and using websphere 7.0 Server.

When I try to start the server facing below issue.

```
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file E:\Program
           Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1\startServer.log
ADMU7701I: Because server1 is registered to run as a Windows Service, the
           request to start this server will be completed by starting the
           associated Windows Service.
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file E:\Program

           Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1\startServer.log

ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile

ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1

ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.

ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. startServer.log,

           SystemOut.log(or job log in zOS) and other log files under

           E:\Program

           Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1 should

           contain failure information.

ADMU7704E: Failed while trying to start the Windows Service associated with
           server: server1; 
probable error executing WASService.exe: Starting
           Service: gh-vdistlsv153Node02
Service failed to start.  startServer
           return code = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the error as meaning that RAD believes that your webspehere is installed as a Windows service and that service is failing to start.

You'll need to systematically try to figure out what's going on.

I would first look in the directory

```
IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1
```

Do you see the SystemOut and SystemErr files for the app server being created? If so open them up and look for errors there.

I think more likely you won't see those files, in which case it implies that the service is not getting as far as launching the Java.

So try starting the service by hand from control panel... what happens? Have a look a the service configuration.

Edited: The error you find is a known problem, you need to download a fix:[from here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&q1=%22Cannot%20load%20XSL%20files%22&uid=swg1PK71997&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&cc=us&lang=en)

Comment: Thanks for your response. When i opened the SystemErr I can see the below error                                                                 "Cannot load XSL files from E:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\plugins\com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar"

Comment: Likely solution added to my answer